# What causes problems with this piece of code?

Tags: user-input, pascal

I was just wondering why this certain problem happens to me. If you can help me, I will appreciate it.

```
Program factorial;
uses crt;
var
  f, i: Integer;
begin
  f:=1;
  for i:=1 to 5 do
    f:= f * i;
  write(f);
  readkey;
end.
```

Okay, That works fine and the result is 120. And it's true.

Now, here's the problem. If I asked the user to enter the value of the number, it won't work.

```
Program factorial;
uses crt;
var
  i,r: Integer;
begin
  write('Enter the number');
  read(r);

  for i:=1 to r do
    r:= r * i;

  write(r);
  readkey;
end.
```

If I wrote 5, the output will be 600.

Comment: Do you not indent your code? If not, programming will be very hard. If you do, please indent it on SO also.

Comment: By the way, why are you using Pascal?

Comment: What a broken way to edit the title of this question...

Comment: +1 for Pascal, although you should perhaps think about switching to FreePascal or Delphi :)

Comment: +1, I have not looked at a pascal program in over 20 years!

Comment: well +1 if I come back in 2 hours :-(

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with this website, and of course I do intent my code, also my mother language isn't English, so I'm sorry for that and thanks for fixing it. And why you wanna know why I'm using Pascal ?

Comment: "And why you wanna know why I'm using Pascal?" That's like saying "Why do you want to know why I'm wearing a banana peel on my head?" Answer: It's unusual.

Comment: I study it at the college, That's why.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning Pascal.  It's a tool, not a religion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the value r as the stopping condition of the loop and modifying the value in the loop.

```
Program factorial;
uses crt;
var
    i,r, f: Integer;
begin
  write('Enter the number');
  read(r);
  f := 1;
  for i:=1 to r do
     f:= f * i;
  write(f);
  readkey;
end.
```

Answer (score 4):

You reuse the `r` variable. If you input `5` for `r` your program will in effect one to many times. You should start with `1` as the first `f`.

```
Program factorial;
uses crt;
var
    i,r, f: Integer;
begin
    write('Enter the number');
    read(r);
    f:=1
    for i:=1 to r do
        f:= f * i;
    write(r);
    readkey;
end.
```

Comment: I understand why you say that. But if you for example use 5 as the input, you will loop 5 times. The first for r will be 5, but should be 1. In effect this is multiplying one time to many.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. I believe your 2nd and 3rd sentence is wrong.

Comment: His solution and your solution loop the same number of times. How does he have an off-by-one error in his loop?

Comment: His solution uses the value that was read from the user as the value to multiply with. His first example does this right, but the second example reuses the variable instead of declaring a new one.

Comment: @Peter, yes you are correct, but that is not an off-by-one error. That's why I was confused by what you said.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Program factorial;
uses crt;
var
i,r,x: Integer;
begin
write('Enter the number');
read(x);
r:=1
for i:=1 to x do
r:= r * i;
write(r);
readkey;
end.
```

Comment: I think that's wrong. You don't keep the value in the loop, but overwrite it every time.

Comment: +1 for keeping the original indentation. Helpful while still poking at the original silliness.

Comment: @Peter Stuifzand, good catch.  I hate programs that use single letter variables! makes it confusing